# SQL Server: Accurate Row Estimates without Histogram?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I'm exploring the optimizer in SQL Server, particularly histograms and I'm seeing some strange, results.

If I execute the query below, where I know there is no histogram on the field, SQL Server outputs a row estimate equal to the actual the result. If I were to run the same query where I use `DECLARE @i NUMERIC(19,2) = 30.0` instead of a constant `WHERE [Rate] < @i`, the estimate is `94.8` as I would expect for the shown query since the database has no statistics on the field.

[image: Query Estimate]

So my question is why is SQL Server outputting the correct result when it has no statistics on the field?

---

When turning off `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` as indicated by my answer, I experience some odd behaviour on the row estimates.

A constraint exists on the table restricting `[Rate]` to be between `6.5 - 200.0`. The estimates vary a lot when experimenting depending on if `>` is used or `>=` as well as `24.0` or `64` format queries where the predicate shows an implict conversion to type`money`.

For `WHERE [Rate] > 6.5` the estimate is `28.44` which then stops at rates above `100`.

For `WHERE [Rate] > 7` where decimals are excluded, the `28.44` estimate runs all the way up to `255`

For `WHERE [Rate] >= 6.5` the `28.44` estimate runs up to about `100` then changes to `17.7764` up to `1000` before the estimate drops to 1.

So there doesn't seem to be much consistency. It seems like SQL Server is aware of the constraint based on some of the queries I'm experimenting with, but it also ignores its presence at times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, as you noticed, SQL Server will automatically create missing statistics (where possible) when compiling an execution plan, if the database option `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` is on.

When statistics are not available, the default guess for an unknown inequality predicate is 0.3 (30%). When you use a local variable, the value in the variable cannot be sniffed (unless `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is also specified). With a table cardinality of 316, the estimate is 0.3 * 316 = 94.8.

When you use a constant literal, the value is sniffed. Without statistics, it cannot use this sniffed value to check the histogram as it normally would, but it can judge its impact on the `CHECK` constraint (the one limiting Rate values to between $6.50 and $200).

If the sniffed value does not exclude the check constraint range *completely*, the estimate is based on the 0.09 (9%) guessed selectivity for a `BETWEEN` predicate (from the check constraint). 316 * 0.09 = 28.44.

If the sniffed value does exclude the check constraint range completely, the estimate is always 1 row (the cardinality estimator (almost) never produces an estimated number of rows less than 1).

If the query is simple enough to qualify for a trivial plan, and it is considered safe for simple parameterization, the constant literal is replaced with a parameter marker e.g. `@1`. This happens for a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS EPH 
WHERE EPH.Rate > $200;
```

The execution plan shows an estimate of 1 row:

[image: Plan]

And the Scan Predicate shows a parameter marker:

[image: Properties]

If simple parameterization is prevented, e.g. by adding a clause that compares a constant with a constant:

```
SELECT * 
FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS EPH 
WHERE EPH.Rate > $200
AND 1 = 1;
```

Without parameterization, this plan can never be reused with a different value for the parameter, so the optimizer can statically eliminate table access on the basis that the check constraint prevents any rows being returned. The resuting plan is:

[image: Constant scan]

Finally, be careful with types. The type of the Rate column is *money*, not *decimal*. Conversions can affect cardinality estimation in complicated ways. Specify a *money* literal with the $ prefix, or use an explicit `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

---

The internal details of cardinality estimation are not documented publicly (probably to avoid endless ever more detailed questions and complaints when things change), but there are a range of resources out there to aid you in this area. Just remember most of this is unoffical and so not supported by anyone. Some aspects are actually dangerous.

Some apply only to the original (pre-2014) cardinality estimator, some explain general principles applicable to both, and some are applicable to the "new" CE only. The following is not meant as an authoritative or complete list, just the ones that came to mind immediately:

- [The SQL Server 2014 Cardinality Estimator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn673537.aspx)
- [13 Things You Should Know About Statistics and the Query Optimizer](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/13-things-you-should-know-about-statistics-and-the-query-optimizer/)
- [Cardinality Estimation (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600374.aspx)
- [Constant Folding and Expression Evaluation During Cardinality Estimation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175933.aspx)
- [Statistics Used by the Query Optimizer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd535534.aspx)
- [Plan Caching and Recompilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn148262.aspx)
- [Nacho Alonso Portillo's blog (MSFT)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ialonso/) (search for cardinality)
- [Dima Piliugin's blog](http://www.queryprocessor.com/category/cardinality-estimation/)
- [SQLblog.com posts](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/tags/Cardinality/default.aspx)
- [SQLperformance.com posts](http://sqlperformance.com/tag/cardinality)
- Microsoft SQL Server Internals (book) Kalen Delaney et al.

Answer (score 1):

What I noticed is that, when `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` is on, then SQL Server is silently computing the histogram on the field before I run the query.

When I turn `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` off and execute the same query, I get a much more plausible estimate (considering it doesn't have the statistics). See below:

[image: Auto Create Off]